# jars not signed when lauched in browser, but not in javaws

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

I have a small webstart application on a local webserver, accesable at localhost:5000/games/game.jnlp accessing that through Firefox and Chromium leads to the following error:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. 
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:778)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:552)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:889)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Application Error: Cannot grant permissions to unsigned jars. Application requested security permissions, but jars are not signed.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.setSecurity(JNLPClassLoader.java:312)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:232)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:330)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:770)
    ... 2 more
```

which pops up in the Swing style error message.

My JNLP file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <jnlp
    spec="1.0+"
    href="game.jnlp"
    >

  <information>
    <title>Space Shapes</title>
    <vendor>WorldsProject</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.worldsproject.org"/>
    <description>A game where you must shoot shapes in space.</description>
    <description kind="short">A game where you must shoot shapes in space.</description>
  </information> 
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>   
  <resources>
    <j2se href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.4+" max-heap-size="512m"/>
    <jar href="game.jar"/>  
    <jar href="resources.jar"/>
    <jar href="slick.jar"/>
    <jar href="jogg-0.0.7.jar"/>    
    <jar href="jorbis-0.0.15.jar"/>
    <jar href="lwjgl.jar"/>
    <nativelib href="lwjgl-libs.jar"/>
  </resources>

  <application-desc main-class="org.worldsproject.fluxware.spaceshapes.SpaceShapesGame"/>

</jnlp>
```

I've confirmed everything is signed correctly with

```
jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose
```

I've look at the jnlp with JaNeLA, all green and yellow messages, no errors at all. I've tested other webstarts, all of which work, except mine.

EDIT, a link to all my jars and jnlp file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hzagv1e4t4jr43t/WA-LVXp5tc

Comment: What is the JNLP?  Be sure to validate the JNLP file(s) using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/). Is it an applet or application?  What HTML is used to launch it?  Why do I need to ask 3 questions to help you answer 1?

Comment: Instead of webstart you could also use the applet mode and create a window for the components. See this http://pastebin.com/f4cjQBs6

Comment: Maybe you didn't sign your jar. Since `javaws` is launched on a localhost jnlp, it works. But when it is called through a browser, it thinks that it is from the  `internet`

Comment: @AndrewThompson JNLP added. JaNeLA gives me green and yellows, no errors. It's an application. No HTML, a direct link (as in URL bar) gives the error.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati jar is verified as signed using jarsigner -verify game.jar and jarsigner -verify resources.jar

Comment: @Atrus Could you list what permissions you need for your game?

Comment: Just in case, all jars need to be signed with the same certificate.

Comment: This also depends on the archives and extensions referenced in http://slick.cokeandcode.com/demos/slick.jnlp  JaNeLA did not report any red elements for it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson There were errors with the extensions. I've gotten rid of the extension and am now only using local jars. I've confirmed everything is signed by me (and only me). Same error. Other webstarts work, just not mine.

Comment: Make sure you uninstall all extensions and the app. from the JCP between tests.

Answer (score 1):

If your jnlp is initializing using command line then you need to set **that** location of javaws **(Sun JDK)** in your browser too i.e when your browser aks to open your javaws application give path to your **sun java** location.

And also if the href denotes a relative URL, it must reference a location that is a subdirectory of the codebase.  Specify URL in your codebase.